# Alternatives for padding, margin and transparent-border in css?

Tags: css, html-email

I am trying to prepare mark up for an HTML email content. I have a table as show below. The "label"s appear to the extreme left of the td and I need to introduce some space of 10px just before the labels. I cannot use padding/margin/tr td:first-child{border-left: 10px solid transparent} because each of these 3 options is failing in one or the other email client(Outlook, Hotmail e.t.c).

Can any one please help me providing an alternative that introduces some space before "label"s in the table cells.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" id="txn-info-container" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
    <tr>
        <td width="25">
        </td>
        <td width="550">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>label</td>
                        <td>Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>label</td>
                        <td>value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>label</td>
                        <td>value</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="25">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note : The table within the td of width 550 comes from a CK-Editor so no html changes can be made to this particular table.

Comment: What about setting `<table style="table-layout:fixed">` and `<td style="width: moreThanEnough px; text-align: right;">`? Designing for email often calls for very ugly ideas.

Comment: `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this in Litmus and it works great. It allows you to target the nested table and ignore the external table.

```
<style>   
  table table {
    background: #f00;
    Margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;

  }
  @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    table table {
      background: #f0f;
      Margin-left: 0px!important;
    }
  }    
</style>
```

`table table` will target the inner table. `Margin-left` and `padding-left` will target every email client and add a 10px left space. The issue is that Apple Mail will add both, which creates a 20px gap. So the `@media` query targets webkit and tells it to make `Margin-left: 0px;`. The `background` color is added for testing purposes. It's not needed for the solution.

You could try `border-left: 10px solid transparent;` as an option. You would not need the webkit `@media` query. I just wanted to give you a way to easily target the nested table.

Good luck.

Comment: This helped. Thanks.. The styles for the table are not getting applied in gmail(mobile and web). Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @AnUser, If this is not working in Gmail, then you have other css that is interfering with your results. I checked Android 5 & 6 and it doesn't work.   You have a solution that works with almost everything. If you want it to work with everything, you need to tell your client to inline their CSS to that table.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding `text-indent: 10px;` to the cells, assuming they’re short words or phrases and won’t break onto multiple lines.